World moving algorithm doesn't work as intended
So I'm working on a voxel engine in C++, and I've put together an algorithm for moving the world based on a new position (only in the +x/+y direction). It works as follows:

Allocate a buffer for holding old chunk pointers
Copy current chunk pointers into the buffer, and zero the current chunk pointers buffer
Loop through each chunk in the old chunk buffer, checking if their coordinates lie within the bounding box of the moved world
If they do, copy the pointer at relative indices into the current chunk buffer
Otherwise, delete the chunk data
Finally, fill in all blank (NULL) spaces in the current chunk buffer with new chunk indices with the correct (x, y) coordinates
After, delete the allocated old chunk pointer buffer

I attempted to write the algorithm on my other computer while away, and got it to work in the way I expected. However, upon arriving home and running it on my main computer, it no longer works and produces erroneous results.
Upon further testing I can confirm that all functions used within the move function are correct and function as intended. The problem lies within the move function and I suspect it to be some form of memory corruption.
Here is the move function:
void Level::move(i64 x, i64 y) {
    Chunk **old = new Chunk*[this->view_distance * this->view_distance];

    // some of the edge chunks might need to be updated
    std::vector<Chunk*> mesh_update_chunks = this->get_edge_chunks();

    this->corner_x = x;
    this->corner_y = y;

    // copy all chunk pointers into old
    for (u32 i = 0; i < this->view_distance; i++) {
        std::memcpy(
            (char*)old + i * sizeof(Chunk*) * this->view_distance,
            this->loaded_chunks[i],
            sizeof(Chunk*) * this->view_distance
        );
        std::memset(
            this->loaded_chunks[i],
            0,
            sizeof(Chunk*) * this->view_distance
        );
    }

    // check if a chunk remains in bounds, placing it at the correct index into
    // the chunk array if it does
    for (u32 i = 0; i < this->view_distance; i++) {
        for (u32 j = 0; j < this->view_distance; j++) {
            Chunk *c = old[j + i * this->view_distance];
            if (c->x >= this->corner_x && c->y >= this->corner_y &&
                c->x <=
                    (this->corner_x + this->view_distance * CHUNK_SIZE_XZ) &&
                c->y <=
                    (this->corner_y + this->view_distance * CHUNK_SIZE_XZ)) {
                // chunk remains in bounds
                u32 index_x = (c->x - this->corner_x) / CHUNK_SIZE_XZ;
                u32 index_y = (c->y - this->corner_y) / CHUNK_SIZE_XZ;

                this->loaded_chunks[index_x][index_y] = c;
                continue;
            }

            // if the chunk that is being deleted is in our mesh_update_chunks
            // vector, then we need to erase it
            mesh_update_chunks.erase(
                std::remove(
                    mesh_update_chunks.begin(),
                    mesh_update_chunks.end(),
                    c
                ), mesh_update_chunks.end()
            );

            // delete all data allocated to the chunk
            c->destroy();
            delete c;
        }
    }

    // fill in all of the deleted chunks with new chunks at the correct
    // coordinates
    for (u32 i = 0; i < this->view_distance; i++) {
        for (u32 j = 0; j < this->view_distance; j++) {
            if (this->loaded_chunks[i][j] == NULL) {
                this->loaded_chunks[i][j] = new Chunk;
                this->loaded_chunks[i][j]->x =
                    i * CHUNK_SIZE_XZ + this->corner_x;
                this->loaded_chunks[i][j]->y =
                    j * CHUNK_SIZE_XZ + this->corner_y;

                this->level_generator.run(this->loaded_chunks[i][j]);
                mesh_update_chunks.push_back(this->loaded_chunks[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // mesh all of the chunks that require it
    for (const auto &c : mesh_update_chunks) {
        c->mesh();
    }

    delete[] old;
}

I have not been able to find any bugs though, and upon attempting a trace table I also found no issues with the code as is.
Does anyone know where the error could be?

Please provide a [mre] and also show the expected as well as the erroneous result.

Why are you using memset and memcpy btw? Why not just use the assignment operator? Also note that you should use nullptr instead of NULL since C++11.

In this context, how would I use the assignment operator instead of memset or memcpy

From what I can tell: old[i * view_distance] = std::exchange(loaded_chunks[i], nullptr); would replace both memcpy and memset - but it's hard to tell since we don't know what loaded_chunks is, so please show a [mre].

Chunk **old = new Chunk*[this->view_distance * this->view_distance];  looks like you're still coding in "C"? In current C++ you would hardly ever see "new/delete". Time to learn about std::vector. Where did you learn "C++" from? All these this-> should not be necessary either.

FYI:  Having to state this-> everywhere takes away the readability of the code.

Also moving the whole world seems a bit inefficient to me.

std::vector<Chunk*> mesh_update_chunks = this->get_edge_chunks(); -- You do realize that mesh_update_chunks is a copy, and not the actual vector of edge chunks?  Is this your intention, to work with a copy?  All of those erase and push_back's you are doing on mesh_update_chunks is not affecting the original vector.

@PaulMcKenzie the function simply returns a vector containing pointers to the edge chunks which exist as dynamically allocated memory, thus the intention is to work on a copy. Furthermore, since the entire program is roughly 3kloc, it wouldn't be feasible to post a working example, instead I would rather outline the algorithm that is causing issues to be more concise. The this-> usage is just my own stylistic choice.

Re: "the function simply returns a vector" - The function doesn't return anything.
It doesn't matter how big the rest of the program is. Reduce it into a [mre] where you don't get the expected result after having called this function. Remove everything from this function that is not necessary to display the problem too.

Oh, and regarding replacing memcpy and memset, I just noticed that you copy all of them so you could replace the whole loop with std::copy_n(loaded_chunks, view_distance, old); std::fill_n(loaded_chunks, view_distance, nullptr);
